# How to validated editText when user type certain digit for 2 conditions in editTextview

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

The thing is I want to validate edit text,

1. If user select Id type Saudi from dropdown then id number should start from 1 to 10(max 10 digits).
2. If user select Id type Iqama from drop down the id number should start from 2 to 10(max 10 digits)

Here below I'm sharing some line of that done my me,

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) 
{
    String enteredString = charSequence.toString();

    if(getIDType.equalsIgnoreCase("Saudi ID"))
    {
        if (!enteredString.startsWith("1"))
        {
            mRegImgIDNumberEdt.setError("start with 1 digit");
        }
    }
    else if (getIDType.equalsIgnoreCase("Iqama")) 
    {
        if (!enteredString.startsWith("2"))
        {            
            mRegImgIDNumberEdt.setError("start with 2 digit");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is dropdown? Is it AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: getIDType is variable that get value from drop down